# How do I override the Telerik MVC Grid editor popup when using ClientTemplates and AjaxBinding

Tags: razor, telerik-mvc

I've got a list of user roles that I'm trying to display in my grid column and trying to set up a custom template for in the edit pop-up.

I tried taking the tac of using the display/editor templates but found out that ajax binding doesn't support these (As the model is always null). So the fix for the column side is using .ClientTemplate on the column in question... which works in the following simplified example of my table...

```
@( Html.Telerik().Grid<UserSearchModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(keys => { keys.Add(p => p.UserId); })
    .Columns(columns =>
           {
               columns.Bound(o => o.UserId).Visible(false) ;
               if(Context.User.IsInRole("Admin")) columns.Bound(o=>o.CompanyName).Width(100);
               columns.Bound(o => o.RolesModel).ClientTemplate("<strong><#= RolesModel.RoleName #></strong>");
               columns.Command(commands =>
               {
                   commands.Edit().ButtonType(type);
               }).Width(180).Title("Commands");       
           })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                   .Select("_AjaxBinding", "Users")
                           .Update("Edit", "Users")
                               .Insert("Create", "Users")
                 )
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Pageable(p=> p.PageSize(13))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height("400px"))
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable()
```

)

But that doesn't pass over to the edit popup... so my question is how do I manage to override the popup to show a custom display for the column I've assigned the .ClientTemplate to?

I've tried using the WindowBuilder (.Window(w=>w.Content("...content stuff here...")) to no avail. The default edit window pops up each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more information about editing of nested objects in ASP.NET MVC I will suggest you check [this blog post.](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/10-09-30/using_nested_complex_objects_with_asp_net_mvc_editor_templates.aspx)

[Maybe this help topic will help too.](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-display-and-editor-templates.html#EditorTemplates)

You can also specify partial view, which can be used as editor form:

```
.Editable(editing => editing.TemplateName("TemplateName"))
```

Comment: While neither of those blog solutions works with ajax binding... the actual code you supplied seems to do the trick I would like to point out that in order to reach the popup requirement the tag has to actually look like:

 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("User"))

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the same functionality by using convention. I specified the GridEditMode as PopUp and then placed a view with the same name as my model at the following path

~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplate/ModelName.cshtml

I did this because the grid has children of the same type and I don't actually need to specify the template.